# Issue with HUB Usb 3.0 and Macbook Air M1

Tags: usb

I own a Macbook Air M1 13''.
I have a HUB USB 3.0 active powered where are connected:

1. A Korg musician keyboard
2. A Behringer Audio Interface
3. A small MIDI - USB controller (ICON I-Pad).

At first connection, everything worked. After second opening of Reper (a DAW), the controller became unavailable.

Looking into the USB information, I got as following:

[image]

And more detail:

[image]

Seems recursively placecd the USB itself (see also the strange version, 90.x).

KROSS2 and UMC404 are correctly recognized and in effect they are under the USB2.0 Hub, at "first level".

Comment: What's the make and model of the USB Hub?

Comment: It's an Amazon Basic: https://tinyurl.com/bdfmh7p8

Widely used in keyboards community.

By the way I tried to connect the ICON directly, without the HUB, with no luck.

Comment: I assume you're running the [REAPER DAW](https://www.reaper.fm/index.php) on your Mac. Make sure you're running the latest version of the app. On the Downloads page, it says: "macOS 10.15+ • REAPER v6.82 - 25MB • Universal for Intel and ARM64" I've never heard of this app, and it is downloading to my mac as I type this comment. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, it is updated to last version. ICON it is invisible also for Camelot.